# How to create a trigger in mysql Before Insert to concatenate value with timestamp

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

my sql query like this,

`insert into transfer_job (job_name, status) values ('Drift', 'Pending');`

here i have to replace coming **job_name** `Drift` with `Drift_20180317` (have to concatenate timestamp along with it)

which trigger should i use?

```
1) Before Insert,
2) After Insert
```

and how to made trigger for this?

i am using mysql Database and `mysqlworkbench`

i am new to trigger hope i explained well...

Answer (score 0):

I did it,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`User`@`%` TRIGGER `transfer_job_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `transfer_job` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

set NEW.job_name = concat(NEW.job_name,'_',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"));
END
```